# d3 time format returning null

Tags: javascript, datetime, d3.js

I have the below code I'm trying to formate with `d3.time.format()` the date I am passing in as an example in the `time` variable is `Thu Dec 24 04:59:54`. According to the documentation, the d3 time formatter is strict and will return  `null` if the `format()` parameters don't match the time that's passed in to be parsed, but as far as I Can tell, I am passing in the correct format, but still getting null.

```
time = "Thu Dec 24 04:59:54";
parseTime = d3.time.format("%a%b%e%H:%M:%S");    
console.log("PARSE TIME" + parseTime.parse(time));
```

EDIT: This is the documentation that I'm using 
 https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#format

Answer (score 2):

It's because your `.format` isn't taking spaces into account, so you will want to change it to:

```
parseTime = d3.time.format("%a %b %e %H:%M:%S");
```

To work with your example. Or you can remove the space from the `time` variable before applying `.parse`.

Comment: neither works. I'm still getting the same null error. I went ahead and added the documentation I'm following.

Comment: @ralphie9224 I was able to get it working in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tz0q1yyx/).